# How do i correct this query?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT column1_value, column2_value 
  FROM some_table
 WHERE column2_value IN (a,lot,of,comma,separated,values)
   AND column1_value NOT IN (SELECT column1_value, 
                                    column3_value 
                               FROM some_table 
                              WHERE column3_value = some_number)
ORDER BY something DESC
LIMIT 4
```

But i keep getting an error, what is wrong?

Can't i do IN and then NOT IN?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
AND column1_value NOT IN (SELECT column1_value, 
                                column3_value 
                           FROM some_table 
                          WHERE column3_value = some_number)
```

Notice the inner subquery?

```
SELECT column1_value, column3_value 
FROM some_table 
WHERE column3_value = some_number
```

You are returning two columns in the data-set! It should just be

```
SELECT column1_value 
FROM some_table 
WHERE column3_value = some_number
```

Or whatever (single!) column you want to test against.

Answer (score 1):

the error is on this part

```
NOT IN (SELECT column1_value, column3_value 
        FROM some_table 
        WHERE column3_value = some_number)
```

as you can see you have return multiple columns from your subquery. it should only return *ONE* column when getting value(s) from subquery.

try using `LEFT JOIN`,

```
SELECT  column1_value, column2_value 
  FROM  some_table
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  column1_value,  column3_value 
            FROM    some_table   
            WHERE column3_value = some_number
        ) x ON sometable.column1_value = x.column1_value
 WHERE  column2_value IN (a,lot,of,comma,separated,values) AND
        x.colName IS NULL
ORDER   BY something DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not allowed to select more than one column in the second sub query.

Answer (score 0):

In the part:

```
(SELECT column1_value, column3_value FROM some_table WHERE column3_value = some_number)
```

You have more than one value selected, its a tupel of values.